# Python- Substract matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I need some help in order to write good code to substract matrix.

For example: sparse_matrices([{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6, (9,10): 7}, {(2,7): 0.5, (4,2): 10}])

Output:{(1, 3): -4, (2, 7): 0.5, (9, 10): -7, (4,2): -10}

I Dont want to use numpy

### edit - copy from comment

```
lst=([{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6, (9,10): 7}, {(2,7): 0.5, (4,2): 10}]) 
A= lst[0] 
B= lst[1] 
C= lst[2] 
F={} 
for k, v in A.items(): 
    for k1,v1 in B.items(): 
         for k2,v2 in C.items(): 
              F[k] =(v-(B.get(k,0)+C.get(k,0))) 
print(F) 
>> {(1, 3): -4, (2, 7): 0.5}
```

Comment: So you have a list of `dict`?  You'll have to do usual Python list and dict operations.

Comment: This is my list: lst=([{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6, (9,10): 7}, {(2,7): 0.5, (4,2): 10}])
This list include 3 lists of dict

I need to write a code that run => F= A-B-C
output:[{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6}])

Comment: You just repeated the question!

Comment: Little, Just marked that F=lst 1-lst2-lst3.

Its a tough question for me...

Comment: Do you know how to work with python lists and dicts?  A `collections.defaultdict` might streamline the code a bit, but isn't essential.  Approach the problem in small steps, making `F` a copy of `lst1`, then subtracting `lst2, etc.

Comment: This is my code: 
lst=([{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6, (9,10): 7}, {(2,7): 0.5, (4,2): 10}])
A= lst[0]
B= lst[1]
C= lst[2]

F={}

for k, v in A.items():
    for k1,v1 in B.items():
        for k2,v2 in C.items():
         F[k] =(v-(B.get(k,0)+C.get(k,0)))
print(F)

>> {(1, 3): -4, (2, 7): 0.5}

Not good yet

Comment: You need added code to handle the cases where `k1` and `k2` are not in `A` (`k`).

Comment: Could you please show me that?

Comment: should use OrderedDict instead of dict because dict is not ordered by nature. So, your matrix row and columns might be changed if you using dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [219]: lst=([{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6, (9,10): 7}, {(2,7): 0.5, (4,2): 10}])
```

Using defaultdict for convenience:

```
In [220]: from collections import defaultdict
In [221]: dd = defaultdict(int)
In [222]: dd
Out[222]: defaultdict(int, {})
In [223]: dd.update(lst[0])
In [224]: dd
Out[224]: defaultdict(int, {(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1})
In [225]: for adict in lst[1:]:
     ...:     for k,v in adict.items():
     ...:         dd[k] = dd[k]-v
     ...: 
In [226]: dd
Out[226]: defaultdict(int, {(1, 3): -4, (2, 7): 0.5, (9, 10): -7, (4, 2): -10})
```

With a regular `dict` we have to use a conditional `get`, that returns 0 if the key isn't found.

```
In [227]: dd = dict()
In [228]: dd.update(lst[0])
In [229]: for adict in lst[1:]:
     ...:     for k,v in adict.items():
     ...:         val = dd.get(k,0)
     ...:         dd[k] = val-v
     ...: 
In [230]: dd
Out[230]: {(1, 3): -4, (2, 7): 0.5, (9, 10): -7, (4, 2): -10}
```